# Is there a way to  search by aspect ratio in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to add useful aspect-ratio search to Lighroom?

The present interface (LR 3.2) gives only 3 options: Landscape, Portrait and Square.
Those seem more like orientations than aspect-ratios to me.

I'd like to be able to see all the aspect ratios in catalog (3:2, 4:3, 2:1, etc) and filter by those. It is often the case that media requires a specific aspect ratio and this would make finding a matching image much more efficient. It is much hard to find an image that can be cropped to some specific ratio than one that was intended that way (I adhere to the 'fill-the-frame' principal, so I usually know in advance if I'm going to crop, and once its done, that's it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Looks like there is no easy solution. Here is how I manage for now. It's neither automatic nor perfect and requires a little discipline but gets you a good part of the way there.*

**For cropped images, I used hierarchical keywords since *Smart Collections* are not flexible enough yet to distinguish between exact aspect ratios.** Like this:

[image]

This is the part that requires discipline since, every time an image is cropped to one of these unusual-but-even aspect ratios, the right keyword must be applied. For example, images with 2:1 aspect ratio get the 2x1 keyword.

This obviously leaves out images with odd aspect ratios. Lucky for me, I only crop 1.2% of images.

**For standard aspect ratios, I created an *Aspect Ratio Collection Set* and *Smart Collections* for each aspect ratio.** Like this:

[image]

Above *3x2* is a Smart Collection which selects on:

- *Cropped* is *False*
- *keywords* does not contain *AspectRatio*
- *Camera* contains *DSLR K-5 K-7 K20D K10D EOS REBEL S5Pro E-5 E-620 SLT D3 D300 ...*

Where **....** is actually a long list of Nikon DSLR, since like Pentax, there is no identifying keyword for all of them. In the case of the *4x3* collection, that would be:

- *Cropped* is *False*
- *keywords* does not contain *AspectRatio*
- *Camera* contains *PowerShot Coolpix Finepix DiMAGE DMC DSC E-P1 E-PL2 Photosmart Optio Tough Stylus X70 XZ-1 Exilim EasyShare*
- *camera* does not contain *S5Pro*

It is a little easier since fixed-lens cameras are grouped into families by nearly everyone, for some reason you will notice the Pentax X70 does not say 'Optio'. Also note the Fuji S5Pro is part of the Finepix line, so it must be excluded explicitly.

**Excluding the *AspectRatio* keyword hierarchy from these collections lets me label images that come out of cameras with a strange aspect ratio.** A number of compact cameras for example support *Sweep Panorama* or *Automatic Panorama* features that produce images that do not correspond to the sensor's native aspect ratio. The same is required for multi-ratio cameras such as many Panasonic Lumix models. When such an image gets imported, simply labeling it with the correct *AspectRatio* keyword such as 7x1, excludes it from incorrectly appearing the the *Aspect Ratio Smart Collection*.

Comment: I am impressed, this is a lot of discipline. I can barely get myself to tag based on Lens.

Comment: Thanks! Guess it depends on priorities, I really do not mind searching for a specific lens (10756 of my images match 'Unknown lens'), but finding a photo that fits is very important to me! My images are cropped very tightly in-camera (can't work without a 100% coverage viewfinder anymore) so I can rarely simply crop an existing image to fit a requested format.

Answer (score 4):

[Any Filter Lightroom Plugin](http://www.johnrellis.com/lightroom/anyfilter.htm) by John Ellis lets you filter by aspect ratio and numeric aspect ratio, as well as filtering on a ton of other fields (it claims [305](http://www.johnrellis.com/lightroom/anyfilter-criteria.htm)).

The way it works is a little strange at first, but pretty easy to get a hang of, especially if you make use of temporary collections to "save" the results.

Answer (score 4):

Jeffrey Friedl just released a plugin that can filter by aspect ratio in various ways. See here: http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer#criteria

However, it requires LR 4.1 or above.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree, Portrait, Landscape, and Square are orientations, not aspect ratios. At the moment, through LR3, there is no way to filter by a specific aspect ratio. It is possible to search by whether an image is cropped or not (true/false), but not by the specific aspect ratio.

This may be due to the fact that Lightroom does not limit you to any well-known, fixed ratios like 3:2 or 4:3, etc. It is possible to crop to any dimension, as well as rotate cropped images, which could complicate any such search algorithm.

Comment: How do we search for cropped images? I looked for that without any luck. I thought of the variety of aspect ratio but looking at the set of focal-lengths with decimals places... it would probably not be much worst. Then there is always the standard set plus 'other' approach.

Comment: Just a note that instead of searching for cropped images, which you can't, you have to create a Collection which selects cropped images for you. That is pretty simple to do.

Comment: That is indeed what I meant...you use a smart collection with the criteria "Cropped: true". Smart collections are technically just saved searches.

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom 4 has this:

[image]

While it's not as drill-down as the exact ratios, at least it gets you the verticals and horizontals.

Comment: You neither read my question nor jrista's answer. This was available in V3 too and are not aspect ratios.