# How can I find images with dimension larger than width/height in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom-4

I have some panorama images in my library and need to handle these differently than the regular images. Usually I color mark these manually, but now I have a rather large set of images and would like to mark them automatically based on dimension.

Is this possible to do with Lightroom. E.g. filter based on "larger than dimension" or aspect ratio?

Comment: You can filter by Aspect Ratio, but this will only let specify whether images are Landscape or Portrait orientation. To do this, choose 'Metadata' in the Filter bar, and in any of the panes, choose 'Aspect Ratio' from the drop-down.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to specify the dimensions as a search criterion. I'd be happy to be proved wrong, however.

Comment: I also do what Nick outlined above, filter based on aspect ratio.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I was more thinking of greater than aspect ratio. Thanks for adding comment and not answer since this was not what I was looking for.

Comment: [Sadly, you cannot filter by aspect ratio without a lot of work.](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/is-there-a-way-to-search-by-aspect-ratio-in-lightroom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Lightroom 4 plugin called [DevMeta](http://www.robcole.com/Rob/ProductsAndServices/DevMetaLrPlugin/) - not tried it - but it does claim to filter by dimensions

Comment: It seems to filter by cropped width/height, but isn't perfect. I also looked into [the extended search plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/extended-search) which supports filtering on number of mega pixels. Maybe a combination of these two would work, but still not perfect. I therefore keep the question open for now and see if there are better solutions. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note that I found a property called pixelcount in DevMeta so extended search is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In LR5 Smart Collections support searching by Size!

As you can see from this screenshot you can now search by a variety of image dimensions[image: LightRoom 5 supports image size searches]